# stripe webhook not called when web call is made

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using NextJs with webhook in the path http://localhost:3000/api/v1/webhook

I have a webhook defined and configured in stripe.
The signature of my hook endpoint is:

```
const webhookHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => { console.log('webhook called')}
```

If I run the cli command

```
stripe trigger charge.succeeded
```

I can see the logging entry in node console but not when calling strip from the webpage.
How do I get the webhook called from calling stripe checkout?

Comment: Which checkout are you referring to? Did you use CLI to forward the events to local webhook endpoint with the guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test#webhook-test-cli)?

Comment: Yes I had the CLI setup but when I moved to work on a different stripe account I forgot to CLI logout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a discussion with Stripe support the issue was that the CLI was logged into the wrong stripe account. I current use 2